# AS3 - Set textfield to _sans

Tags: actionscript-3, text, fonts

I need to set a textfield to _sans if a certain language is used. Usually it uses an embeded font. How can I set it to _sans through AS3?

Thanks.
Uli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using system.Capabilities to detect the systems language setting might not be the best route to take. e.g. you might have an English speaking person working in India who wants to use your file.

You might want to build in some kind of language choosing option.

In this example I set a variable (alphabetToUse) whether the chosen language is latin or not.

```
var myFont:Font;
var alphabetToUse:String;

myFont = new DinReg();

//for latin
var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myFormat.size = 14;
myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT;
myFormat.font = myFont.fontName;

//for anything else
var myDefaultFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myDefaultFormat.size = 14;
myDefaultFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT;
myDefaultFormat.font = "_sans";


var myText:TextField = new TextField();
myText.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
myText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
myText.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
myText.multiline = true;


if(alphabetToUse == "latin") {
    myText.embedFonts = true;
    myText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
} else {
    myText.embedFonts = false;
    myText.defaultTextFormat = myDefaultFormat;
}

myText.border = false;
myText.wordWrap = true;
myText.width = 345;
myText.height = 28;
myText.x = 0;
myText.y = 0;

addChild(myText);

myText.htmlText = "some text";
```

Comment: I get an error **Call to a possibly undefined method DinReg** What  is DinReg?

Comment: That is the name of the font I have embedded into the library. You need to embed your own font into your library, give it a name and use that instead of dinreg

Answer (score 1):

To detect the current language of the client you can use:

```
flash.system.Capabilities.language; //in my case returns "en"
```

To dynamically load a font at run time there are some good tutorials out there, including this one: http://bryanlangdon.com/blog/2007/03/22/loading-fonts-dynamically-in-actionscript-2-and-3/

I hope that helps.

**Edit**

To dynamically change fonts that are already embedded, first turn on font embedding for your individual text fields: (untested code)

```
myTextField_txt.embedFonts = true;
```

Then create and set the text format of the textFields you want changed. Something like:

```
var myformat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myformat.font = "_sans";
myTextField_txt.setTextFormat(myformat);
```

Optionally you can set additional things in the TextFormat, such as size, color, etc..

Comment: I don't want to load a font- I just want to use a _sans system font. How to change the textfield behavior to _sans?

Comment: see edit, if there is a typo or if I missed something let me know.

Comment: @ToddBFisher: probably, if he wants to use _sans, the font should not be embedded: myTextField_txt.embedFonts=false;

Comment: Yeah, I've seen some weird stuff with fonts, as AsTheWormTurns suggests try different options such as not embedding, as well as different fonts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To use the system _sans font use the following code:

```
var tf : TextField = new TextField();  // create a text field
var fmt : TextFormat = new TextFormat(); // create a text format

with(fmt) {
  font = "_sans";  // using sans results in the use of arial on windows and helvetica on MacOS
  size = 12;
  color = 0xFFFFFF;  // white
}

with (tf) { 
  embedFonts = false;   // if you skip this you'll get Times (at least in Windows)
  defaultTextFormat = fmt;
}
```

Not embedding fonts results in smaller swf's >> shorter download time, less traffic.
Especially if you want to be able to use different character sets (russian, greek, chinese) embedding can result in a big swf file size.